# Error importing persist module

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using fedora and wxpython version 2.8.12 .While trying to import wx.lib.agw.persist
I am getting an error saying 
Import Error: No module persist.
Will the module not be there by default with wxPython, if not how do I get this module installed? please help me.

Answer (score 2):

`wx.lib.agw.persist` is new in 2.8.12.1.